# REGEX that matches a paragraph that doesn't contain a word avoiding \n

Tags: regex, scala, regex-negation

I have a REGEX that finds a word inside a paragraph, while avoiding \n.
`(?i)(?<=\b|\\n)cat\b`

1. Something something \ncat\n - match
2. Something something cat - match
3. Something something cats - no match, as expected

I want the negative of this REGEX - does a paragraph **not contain** the word.

1. Something something \ncat\n - no match - contains the word
2. Something something cat - no match - contains the word
3. Something something cats - match
4. Something something \ncatss\n - match

I've tried a Negative lookbehind but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you define what a paragraphs means for you please?